# How do I initialize a 2D array in Angular 11, while populating it with input?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I am building a basic to do app, and I am trying to append a new 2D item with properties Item: string, and completed: boolean. The item value gets read from an html  tag, and added to the array.

How do I initialize the array and can I do it while populating that array?

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input id='listinput' type="text">
  <button id='submitbutton' (click)=addtolist()>Submit</button>
  <button id='clearbutton'>Clear list</button>
</div>
<ul id='itemlist'>list here</ul>
```

JS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


export interface ListInterface{
  todolistarray: {listitem: string, completed: boolean}[]
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todolist',
  templateUrl: './todolist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todolist.component.css']
})
export class TodolistComponent implements OnInit {
 
  addtolist() {
    var todolistarray:ListInterface[]
    var listitemvar = (document.getElementById('listinput') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    alert(listitemvar);
    (document.getElementById('itemlist') as HTMLDataListElement).innerText = listitemvar;
  }
  
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

Thank you in advance for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
    <input id='listinput' type="text" #input>
    <button id='submitbutton' (click)="list.push({ item: input.value, completed: false })">Submit</button>
    <button id='clearbutton' (click)="list = []">Clear list</button>
</div>
<ul id='itemlist'>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list">
    {{ item.item }}. Completed ? {{ item.completed }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
export class TodolistComponent implements OnInit {
  list: { item: string, completed: boolean }[] = [];
}
```